# Delete line after it has been read from file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a function that read lines from a file and process them. However, I want to delete every line that I have read, but without using readlines() that reads all of the lines at once and stores them into a list.

Comment: This is rather hard to follow, can you simplify it? Also, what do you mean by 'documents', 'documents similarities', 'dots'... Ideally provide some small example snippets of what data you have, and what code you are using so far.

Comment: I just want to delete every line that I have read but without using readlines, where I get all of the lines of the file at once. Everytime my function opens the file, I want to delete each line that I have read.

Comment: Delete in the file or do you meant don't store them anymore in the memory?

Comment: Delete them in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is that you run out of memory, then I suggest you use the `for line in file` syntax, as this will only load the lines one at a time:

```
bigFile = open('path/to/file.dat','r')
for line in bigFile:
    processLine(line)
```

If you can construct your system so that it can process the file line-by-line, then it won't run out of memory trying to read the whole file. The program will discard the copy it has made of the file contents when it moves onto the next line.

#### Why does this work when `readlines` doesn't?

In Python there are [iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), which provide an interface to supply one item of a collection at a time, iterating over the whole collection if `.next()` is called repeatedly. Because you rarely need the whole collection at once, this can allow the program to work with a single item in memory instead, and thus allow large files to be processed.

By contrast, the `readlines` function has to return a whole list, rather than an iterator object, so it cannot delay the processing of later lines like an iterator could. Since Python 2.3, the old `xreadlines` read iterator was deprecated in favour of using `for line in file`, because the file object returned by `open` had been changed to return an iterator rather than a list.

This follows the functional paradigm called ['lazy evaluation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), where you avoid doing any actual processing unless and until the result is needed.

#### More iterators

Iterators can be chained together (process the lines of this file, then that one), or otherwise combined using the excellent [itertools](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html) module (included in Python). These are very powerful, and can allow you to separate out the way you combine files or inputs from the code that processes them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I have to import a library for the function processLine because I get NameError: global name 'processLine' is not defined.

Comment: processLine is meant to be a placeholder for my code snippet - replace it with the code you want to use to process a line, or alternatively write a function that processes a single line called `processLine`.

Comment: @PhilH Apparently, OP wanted to remove the lines from the file as soon as they are processed. I'm not sure that's a good idea though :).

Comment: @Maxime: yes, my guess is that it was requested in order to deal with the initial problem that the file was too large, so rather than attempt the deletion I thought I'd suggest iteration first.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, deleting the first line of a file is a costly process. Actually, you are unlikely to be able to do it without rewriting most of the file.

You have multiple approaches that could solve your issue:

1.In python, file objects have an iterator over the lines, may be you can use this to solve your memory issues

```
document_count = 0
with open(filename) as handler:
    for index, line in enumerate(handler):
        if line == '.':
            document_count += 1
```

2.Use an index. Reserve a certain part of your file to the index(fixed size, make sure to reserve enough space, let's say the first 100Ko of your file should be reserved for the index, that's about 100K entries) or even another index file, every time you add a document put it's starting position on the index. Once you know the document position, just use the [seek](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) function to get there and start reading

3.Read the file once and store every document position, this is very similar to the previous idea, except it's in memory which is better performance-wise but you will have to repeat the process every time you run the application (no persistence)